# android setText is delayed inside fragment

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update (inside `Fragment`) `TextView`s before setting `View`. Everything works fine but the `setText` is delayed. The app runs with the values which were pre-set in `android:text="something"` and sometime later the values change into what I want (after like 0.5second). I get the values from firebase.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    UserName = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_user_name);
    UserInfo = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_user_info);

    mDatabase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    return v;
}
```

This is where I fetch the data

```
// here inside onStart i try to setText into textViews
// values are queried from my FirebaseFirestore
@Override
public void onStart() {
    docRef = mDatabase.collection("users").document(uId);
    docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists()){
                User user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);

                UserName.setText(user.getName());
                UserInfo.setText(user.getInfo());
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG,"Document does not exits");
            }
        }
    });
    super.onStart();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, what you're describing sounds exactly like how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Why? Is there some way to stop the delay or what is good practise to avoid this?

Comment: I tried to describe the situation in my answer. Please let me know if that was helpful.

Comment: Database queries take time.  They are not instant.  You have to expect that it takes time to get database results, and that it takes time to send them over the network, which could be very slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to fetch data from a remote server (in your case, this is your firebase database). Even if you have added the `addOnSuccessListener` in your `onStart` function, this creates an asynchronous thread which fetches the desired data from firebase. However, in the meantime, the activity is loaded and you can see the pre-set value in your `TextView`.

If you do not want to show the `TextView` before the data is loaded from the firebase database, you might consider doing the following.

In the `onCreateView` function set the visibility of your `TextView` to `INVISIBLE` like the following.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    UserName = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_user_name);
    UserInfo = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_user_info);

    // Set the visibility to invisible here. So that when the application is loaded, you do not see the pre-set values. 
    UserName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    UserInfo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    mDatabase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    return v;
}
```

And when the data is fetched from firebase and available in your activity, set the visibility of the views to `VISIBLE` again.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    docRef = mDatabase.collection("users").document(uId);
    docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists()){
                User user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);

                UserName.setText(user.getName());
                UserInfo.setText(user.getInfo());

                // Set the visibility to VISIBLE again here
                UserName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                UserInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG,"Document does not exits");
            }
        }
    });
    super.onStart();
}
```

Hope that helps you to understand the scenario.

Edit:

You can consider saving the information frequently used in local storage so that they can be loaded immediately after you open the application. If the information is not that much, you can consider using `SharedPreference` to store the data in the internal storage of your application, so that they can be loaded directly in your application when you are launching your `Fragment`. [Here's how](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) you can save your data in SharedPreference and can retrieve the data from it.

However, you need to consider that, in case of saving (i.e. caching) something in local storage, needs to be updated when the data is changed remotely. Hence, after you fetch the updated data from firebase (or anywhere in your application, where you update the userName or userInfo), you need to update the data stored in the local storage accordingly. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for answer, this works.. but .. is there some better aproach? Lets say the Instagram app, if i click on my profile, there is no delay in updating

Comment: To be more accurate, the Firebase SDK doesn't "create an asynchronous thread" in response to a database query.  It queues some work on a single background thread, and processes all the queries in the order they were queued.  The idea is to be able to kick off many queries without having to create many threads. The results of those queries will be delivered back to the app queued on its UI thread.

Comment: @DougStevenson this is a great explanation. Thank you for this. :)

Comment: @Rasťo, can you please check the update of my answer? Thanks.

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for! Thanks.

Comment: "You can consider saving the information frequently used in local storage so that they can be loaded immediately after you open the application." The Firebase SDK already does this for you by default, it caches any values its listeners retrieve in a local database. But using a `get()` call like this code does bypasses that local cache, to prevent returning stale data. You can tell it to get from the local cache with `docRef.get(Source.CACHE)`, or better yet use a realtime listener to get the value from the local cache straight away, and still check the server for updates.